# The continue statement in my C program doesn't seem to work

Tags: c

I don't know why my program doesn't work. I want it to skip through the numbers I have put in code, but still it keeps showing them. 
         '

```
int main(){
int num;

for(num=1; num<=10; num++)
{
    printf("The num %d is available\n", num);
    if (num== 5 || num== 2 || num==3) {
        continue;
    }

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Outside of functional state, if it is possible to have a more ambiguous title to this question I'm pressed to see how.

Comment: @MaxTheG: "Question"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're printing the output *before* you check whether or not you *want* to print the output.  Swap the logic:

```
if (num== 5 || num== 2 || num==3) {
    continue;
}
printf("The num %d is available\n", num);
```

Or, conversely you can omit the `continue`:

```
if (num != 5 && num != 2 && num != 3) {
    printf("The num %d is available\n", num);
}
```

It's a matter of personal preference and readability, either one should produce the same output.

Comment: Got that, may I ask why are people down voting my question?

Comment: @FahadSaleem: I'm not sure.  Some people down-vote for questions they consider to be too simple.  Honestly, don't take it personally.  I've been serial-downvoted more times than I can count.

Comment: People forget that they were once amateurs too.

Comment: Couldn't one use "break" instead of "continue"?